# My css file is requiring /index.php as part of the url

Tags: apache2, expressionengine

Ive taken a copy of expressionengine from our production server to a dev server and its installed and running. I can access the admin console fine and Ive updated my paths.

The problem is that when I try and view my site the main page loads but no CSS is downloaded. The error Im getting is

> The requested URL /presentation/layout was not found on this server.

I cant access the file from http://localhost/presentation/layout but I can access from

http://localhost/index.php/presentation/layout

Ive updated my .htaccess file from the following guide

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/urls/remove_index.php.html

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

        # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I can access the site now from http://localhost without the index.php but its still looking for it for the CSS file. Any idea how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

First thing: don't put your css file in a template unless you absolutely have to. 
You only need dynamical css files if the styles are depending on the data in a channel like

```
{exp:channel:entries}
.{title} {
color: #{color_custom_field};
}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

If you put it in a template it will be processed by the template parser on every page view. This will add extra queries/processing which isn't needed for a static file.

What version of EE are you on?

All of us EE guys are over at https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/ by the way